AWS Batch Healthcheck
Looks like AWS Batch Job Definition does not support health checks.
I am scheduling long running jobs (containers) using AWS Batch on EC2. Without health checks there is a possibility of jobs stuck in infinite loop and no way to knowing it until maximum time is reached. A health check for these jobs will be very beneficial and save some compute cost.
Any suggestions on how can I implement a health checks for long running Batch Jobs on EC2?
